# Access Denied to CiviMail Opt-Out Form

Tags: civimail, permissions

The Unsubscribe link (in mailings) works fine if I am logged in as administrator, but I have "Access Denied" to the opt-out form if not.

(I have defined an Unsubscribe Group, with public visibility)

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a permission for it. Go to your Drupal -> People -> Permissions and give anonymous (and authenticated) permission to Unsubscribe:

Access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages

Comment: I finally found ; thank you Karin